# How to setup a root domain mirror for a subdomain using .htaccess or php

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain, mirroring

I want a subdomain to mirror the root-domain (ex: sub.root.com mirroring root.com) and I want to accomplish this via .htaccess or php, with .htaccess prefered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((subdomain).)?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[0-9]+)?))$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to write any PHP code or modify `.htaccess`. you can accomplish this by just modifying `/etc/hosts` (Linux) or `%SystemRoot%/Windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts` (Windows)

Comment: You forgot about people without root access